# @aws-amplify/ui-react Sign In button position customization

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I am using `@aws-amplify/ui-react` in my project. I invoked just `AmplifySignIn` component and without any SignUp. I exported a sample project from [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ce42d) and start doing some customization.
This is my SignIn Code.

```
const SignIn = () => (
  <AmplifyAuthenticator style={{
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '100vh',
    backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImage})`,
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
  }}>
    
    <AmplifySignIn hideSignUp={true} slot="sign-in" headerText="" usernameAlias="email" >
      <div slot="federated-buttons">
      </div>
    </AmplifySignIn>
```

I used the same code in my project and try to mimic the UI with the same as like the sample project. But the Sign In button size differs between the sample project and my real project.

The sample project UI:

[image]

The same code displaying the Sign In Button like below:

[image]

Even though I am using the same CSS, why is the Sign In fully centered in my view?

Also, I tried to look at the element how it is rendered in Browser.
In the sample project, I am seeing a slot(secondary-footer-content) added with an empty span like below

[image]

But In my project, I am seeing another div added with class `full-width-footer-content`.

[image]

How can I resolve this to show my Sign In button to be like the sample project? I am not good at CSS. But try to mimic the same as the project.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to fix this issue is by overwriting the CSS generated by aws-amplifyui library.

In your styles.css, add the following code:

```css
.full-width-footer-content {
    width: 153px !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
}
```